# Does matlab neural network toolbox use early-stopping by default?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matlab, artificial-intelligence

I have trained a neural network in **matlab** using the toolbox (code below), but I no longer have a maltab license; does anyone know if the **validation** in this toolbox by default is only to assess the performance of the neural network, or if it is used for **early-stopping** (when the error starts enhancing instead of diminishing, stop training)?

I think I remember seeing something related to this when training the ANN (number of epochs after which the training was stopped by the validation), but like I said I no longer have matlab and I can't find anything about it online... Thanks in advance!

````
% Create a Pattern Recognition Network
hiddenLayerSize = 15;
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize, trainFcn);

% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivision
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 65/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 20/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Choose a Performance Function
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';  % Cross-Entropy

% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
    'plotconfusion', 'plotroc'};

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears on their documentation, yes, validation set is being used for early-stopping (which is pretty typical by the way):

> The training set is used to teach the network. Training continues as
> long as the network continues improving on the validation set.

See [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/wine-classification.html), [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/cancer-detection.html), and [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/crab-classification.html) (their example pages).